# iCloud Drive - Read & Write (NSData)

Tags: objective-c, icloud-drive

Trying to save custom objects as NSData then upload to iCloud **Drive**

any direction?
I tried already the Key-Value Method, but it is limited for 1MB :/

**is it the correct way?**
if yes, how can I read from the iCloud path?

```
+(void)iCloudWrite:(NSData*)data
{

    NSURL* ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];
    NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]  URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"iCloudHistory.zip"];

    MyDocument *mydoc = [[MyDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];
    mydoc.dataContent = data;

    [mydoc saveToURL:[mydoc fileURL] forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForOverwriting completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
     {
         if (success)
         {
             NSLog(@"Synced with icloud");
         }
         else
             NSLog(@"Syncing FAILED with icloud");
     }];
}
```

EDITED:

[image]

Comment: It looks like you and me are working on the same issue at the same till will post answer soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// 1. Any file can be uploaded to iCloud container of any size (yes you should be having that much of space in iCloud) lets take an example SampleData.zip

// 2. This method will upload or sync SampleData.zip file in iCloud container, iCloud actually checks the metadata of your file before it uploads it into your iCloud container (so for first time it will upload the file and from next time it will only upload the changes)

-(void) iCloudSyncing:(id)sender
{
    //Doc dir
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleData.zip"];
    NSURL *u = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:filePath];
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:u];

    //Get iCloud container URL
    NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];// in place of nil you can add your container name
    //Create Document dir in iCloud container and upload/sync SampleData.zip
    NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleData.zip"];
    Mydoc = [[MyDocument alloc] initWithFileURL:ubiquitousPackage];
    Mydoc.zipDataContent = data;

    [Mydoc saveToURL:[Mydoc fileURL] forSaveOperation:UIDocumentSaveForCreating completionHandler:^(BOOL success)
     {
         if (success)
         {
             NSLog(@"SampleData.zip: Synced with icloud");
         }
         else
             NSLog(@"SampleData.zip: Syncing FAILED with icloud");

     }];
}



  // 3 Download data from the iCloud Container

- (IBAction)GetData:(id)sender {

    //--------------------------Get data back from iCloud -----------------------------//
    id token = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];
    if (token == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"ICloud Is not LogIn");
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"ICloud Is LogIn");

        NSError *error = nil;
        NSURL *ubiq = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:nil];// in place of nil you can add your container name
        NSURL *ubiquitousPackage = [[ubiq URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"SampleData.zip"];
        BOOL isFileDounloaded = [[NSFileManager defaultManager]startDownloadingUbiquitousItemAtURL:ubiquitousPackage error:&error];
        if (isFileDounloaded) {
            NSLog(@"%d",isFileDounloaded);
            NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
            //changing the file name as SampleData.zip is already present in doc directory which we have used for upload
            NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RecSampleData.zip"];
            NSString* fileAtPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
            NSData *dataFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:ubiquitousPackage];
            BOOL fileStatus = [dataFile writeToFile:fileAtPath atomically:NO];
            if (fileStatus) {
                NSLog(@"success");
            }
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"%d",isFileDounloaded);
        }
    }
}

//4 voila its done :)
```

Don't forget to add following parameters to your plist

```
<key>NSUbiquitousContainers</key>
    <dict>
        <key>YourCloudContainerID</key>
        <dict>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerIsDocumentScopePublic</key>
            <true/>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerName</key>
            <string>YourCloudContainerName</string>
            <key>NSUbiquitousContainerSupportedFolderLevels</key>
            <string>Any</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

Comment: works great,
don't forget on xCode - to **enable "iCloud Capabilities"**
bless you √

Comment: reason why IOS 10 isn't working?
All device iCloud settings are ON

Comment: @OfirMalachi I did test on iOS 10 works for me, please check you have added necessary iCloud settings in Plist and your provision profile is having a container added.

Comment: what should I add to .Plist file?

Comment: @OfirMalachi updated my answer, make sure to add your CloudContainerName and CloudContainerID respectively.

Comment: what's MyDocument object?

Comment: @Bkillnest, MyDocument is a subclass of UIDocument. Uploading data to iCloud as a UIDocument.